# In Visual Studio Code, launch a Console application in an external window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a Console application open in VS Code. When I press Ctrl-F5, the output of my program is displayed in a DEBUG CONSOLE window, along with other text.

How do I get Visual Studio Code to launch my program in a new console window?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As documented [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md#console-terminal-window) this can be achieved using this setting:

```
"console": "externalTerminal"
```

The settings file is in the solution directory: `.vscode/launch.json` .

Comment: It opens cmd (which is fine). But can we change it to gitbash?

Answer (score 3):

When you're just using Tasks and not Launchers, you can follow the advice [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_can-a-task-use-a-different-shell-than-the-one-specified-for-the-integrated-terminal).

For me on Linux, I changed my shell command in VSCode from `command` to `gnome-terminal -e command`. That did the trick; that's all I had to do.

Note that if you do this you can get rid of the `presentation` option set from your task.

Comment: on a fresh install of ubuntu 21.10 i had to add `"terminal.external.linuxExec": "gnome-terminal",` to the settings

Answer (score 1):

Note that with VSCode 1.78 (Apr. 2023), you will be able to open both:

```
"explorerKind": "both"
```

See [issue 167688](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167688) and [PR 168879](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/168879), available in [VSCode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).